# Защита от повторной отправки формы.

Tags: ооп, php

Ну собственно в этом и проблема. Надо защититься от повторной отправки формы, учитывая тот факт, что форма обрабатывается отдельным классом. Т.е. структура скрипта такова (в общих чертах):

```
<обработчик>
  (условие == true) => Класс::метод (внесение данных в БД)
</обработчик>

<форма>
```

Т.е. форма и обработчик на одной странице, а данные в БД попадают уже через метод подключаемого класса.

P.S. Сессии, куки не предлагать. Из за

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...

Редиректы тоже, т.к. должно быть видно сообщение с результатом обработки формы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если добавить скрытый элемент на форму и фиксировать факт отправки? Можно ли осуществлять повторную отправку при обновлении (повторном открытии) страницы? Еще посмотри, нельзя ли реализовать через дополнительное статическое свойство (поле) класса.

Comment: >Можно ли осуществлять повторную отправку при обновлении (повторном открытии) страницы?

Можно

>А если добавить скрытый элемент на форму и фиксировать факт отправки?

Есть такая идея. При первой отправки формы записывать в базу уникальный ID. И передотправкой формы проверять, есть ли такой в БД, если есть, значит повтор. Но этот вариант будет выполнять запрос к БД при каждом нажатии F5, не скажется ли это на работе БД? Проект высоконагруженный, а "чудиков-вредителей" в интернете хватает.

Answer (score 2):

Надо передавать форму на страницу обработки, обрабатывать, а потом уже редиректить на страницу результатов. Соответственно, на странице обработки не должно выводиться ничего, только кидаться заголовки.

Либо же, обработка формы должна происходить на той же странице, но до вывода чего-либо. В случае отправки формы, можно редиректить на ту же страницу с `&success=true` и рандомным параметром (чтобы исключить кэширование).

Answer (score 1):

А что если так - сделать таблицу и хранить там очередь скажем из последних 10 sql запросов.

Comment: Нечто подобное я написал в комменте к ответу @Вячеслав Кириченко

Comment: Ну а если другой пользователь через 1 сек отправит точно такой запрос?

Comment: Ну да, я не заметил прости. Уникальный id генерировать необязательно можно хранить запрос, что иногда очень полезно или его хэш(хотя по сути это уже есть id). Но в любом случае, не уйти от сохранения информации о последнем запросе.

Comment: Тогда нужно хэшировать id пользователя и запрос

Comment: Безумное решение, у MYSQL есть системные переменные, например timestamp. Что если выбрать самые ненужные и писать такую инфу в них. Какая интересно будет скорость записи и чтения?

Comment: @culebre , прочитав 3 последних ваших комментария, появилась мысль, что вы сам с собой общаетесь. :D

Comment: День просто выдался тяжелый=)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="check" value="<?php echo time();?>" />

if(empty($_POST['check'])) {
  echo 'Баян';
}

if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
// выполнить запрос
unset $_POST['check'];
}
```